# VSCode keybinding shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have keybinding shortcut for checkout to different branch.
I want to know if it’s possible to run automatically git pull after this shortcut.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to combine it with '&&': ```git checkout mybranch && git pull```

Comment: have you tries the `multi-command` extension to combine commands into one